# How to find maximum task running at x time?

Tags: algorithm

Problem description is follows:

There are n events for particular day d  having start time and duration. Example:

```
e1 10:15:06 11ms (ms = milli seconds)
e2 10:16:07 12ms
......
```

I need to find out the time x and n. Where x is the time when maximum events were getting executed.

**Solution I am thinking is:**
Scanning all ms in day d. But that request total 86400000*n calculation. Example

```
Check at 00::00::00::001 How many events are running
Check at 00::00::00::002 How many events are running
Take max of Range(00::00::00::01,00::00::00::00)
```

**Second solution I am thinking is:**

```
For eventi in all events
   Set running_event=1
   eventj in all events Where eventj!=eventi
        if eventj.start_time in Range (eventi.start_time,eventi.execution_time)
           running_event++
```

And then take max of running_event

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: `ms` == miliseconds? What kind of tasks is this?

Comment: @JanDvorak yes. ms == milliseconds.

Comment: This can be solved in `n log n`

Comment: @JanDvorak Using which approach/algorithm Can you please provide name of algo ?

Comment: @VivekGoel: You can store all the start and end points into an array, sort it, and keep track of the number of task going on at each point in time (start or end time). This way, you can find the max number of task running and the time interval. This is also n log n.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm already writing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in `O(n log n)` time:

- Make an array of all events. This array is already partially sorted: `O(n)`
- Sort the array: `O(n log n)`; your library should be able to make use of the partial sortedness ([timSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) does that very well); look into [distribution-based sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsort) for better expected running time.

  - Sort event boundaries ascending w.r.t. the boundary time
  - Sort event ends before sort starts if touching intervals are considered non-overlapping
    (Sort event ends after sort starts if touching intervals are considered overlapping)
- Initialise `running` = 0, `running_best` = 0, `best_at` = 0
- For each event boundary:

  - If it's a start of an event, increment `running`
  - If `running > running_best`, set `best_at` = current event time
  - If it's an end of an event, decrement `running`
- output `best_at`

Comment: Tie-breaking must be properly handled in case the start and end time are the same. Not happening a lot in real life, but possible nevertheless.

Comment: @nhahtdh will make explicit

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the number of points you check by checking only ends of all intervals, for each interval (task) `I` that lasts from `t1` to `t2`, you only need to check how many tasks are running at `t1` and at `t2` (assuming the tasks runs from `t1` to `t2` inclusive, if it is exclusive, check for `t1-EPSILON, t1+EPSILON, t2-EPSILON, T2+EPSILON`.

It is easy to see (convince yourself why) that you cannot get anything better that these cases do not cover.

**Example:**

```
tasks run in `[0.5,1.5],[0,1.2],[1,3]`
candidates: 0,0.5,1,1.2,1.5,3
0 -> 1 tasks
0.5 -> 2 tasks
1 -> 3 tasks
1.2 -> 3 tasks (assuming inclusive, end of interval)
1.5 -> 2 tasks (assuming inclusive, end of interval)
3 -> 1 task (assuming inclusive, end of interval)
```